# Angular 15 HTTPCLIENTXSRFMODULE not working with ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, angular15

The issue I encountered was that my request header did not contain an `x-xsrf-token`. Therefore, `Httpclientxsrfmodule` may not have functioned. Can somebody solve this problem for me? I've spent a week trying to fix the problem.

Here's my middleware:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BackEnd.Handler
{
    public class AntiforgeryTokenMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

        public AntiforgeryTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            _next = next;
            _antiforgery = antiforgery;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
            {
                var context = (HttpContext)state;
                //if (string.Equals(httpContext.Request.Path.Value, "/",    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                //{
                    var tokens = _antiforgery.GetTokens(httpContext);
                httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new  CookieOptions()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    IsEssential = false,
                    Secure = true,
                    Domain = "localhost",
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                });
                //}
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }, httpContext);

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    public static class AntiforgeryTokenMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseAntiforgeryToken(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<AntiforgeryTokenMiddleware>();
    }
    }
}
```

And my `Program.cs`:

```
using BackEnd.Data;
using BackEnd.Filters;
using BackEnd.Handler;
//using BackEnd.Handler;
using BackEnd.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Inject DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options
    => options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString")));

// jwtbearer
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "localhost",
        ValidAudience = "localhost",
        IssuerSigningKey = new     SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["jwtConfig:Key"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cookieOptions =>
{
    cookieOptions.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
    cookieOptions.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    cookieOptions.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    cookieOptions.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";

    cookieOptions.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = redirectContext =>
        {
            redirectContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
}    
);

builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())
);

// cors
builder.Services.AddCors((setup) =>
{
    setup.AddPolicy("default", (options) =>
{
    options.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    options.AllowCredentials();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseCors("default");
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("default");

app.MapControllers();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAntiforgeryToken();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is the `HTTPCLIENTXSRFMODULE` in `app.module.ts` under Imports

```
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
          cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
          headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
        }),
```

I tried also, creating api that generates token and put the xsrf-token to the request header.

here is the code from api:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("antiforgery")]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetToken()
        {
            var tokens = _antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
            Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
            {
                Path = "/",
                HttpOnly = false,
                IsEssential = true,
                Secure = false,
                Domain = "localhost",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            });
            return new OkObjectResult(tokens);

        }
```

and in my angular Services:

```
    login(loginInfos: Array<string>) {
    return this.getAntiForgeryToken().pipe(
          switchMap(tokenResponse => {
            console.log(tokenResponse)

          this.cookieService.set("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenResponse.requestToken)
          const tok = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
          const headers = new HttpHeaders()
              .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
              .set('Access-Control-ALlow-Origin', '*')
              .set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', tok);// Set the token received from the server
              console.log(tok) 
              console.log(headers) 
          
              return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiBaseServerUrl}User/login`, 
              { 
                Email: loginInfos[0],
                Password: loginInfos[1]
              },
              {headers: headers}
              )
                .pipe(
                  map(
                    response => response.token,
                    ),
                    catchError(this.handleError)
                  );
          })
        );
    }


      handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        return throwError(error);
    }
    }
```

I still got error 400 Bad request.

Here's the screenshot of Header:

[image: The cookies I got from api/antiforgery]

[image: 400 bad request when I tried to logged in]

I also tested it with Postman, and when I added the x-xsrf-token to the headers, it functioned as long as the api's cookies were present. However, if I delete those cookies, a bad request will happen.

Here's my screenshot:

[image: Cookies generated when i run the api/antiforgery]

[image: When adding the x-xsrf-token to the header and the value of the xsrf-token cookie, status 200 was received.]